# When using the vue.js, there is a problem that the character is not output if you insert the <>character after the v-model variable declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, frontend

```
<vue-editor id="Leditor" type="textarea" v-model="pandogsogeon"></vue-editor>


var temp =  document.createElement("div");
    temp.textContent = "aasdfas<>asdfad<>"
    
this.pandogsogeon = temp.textContent;
```

From `<`, it is not output to the screen. How can I output all characters including `<`?

Comment: guess it depends what `this.pandogsogeon` actually is - i.e. how it's used

Comment: \^    \ -> success

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem or I didn't understand your problem

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return{
      pandogsogeon: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.createText()
  },
  methods: {
    createText () {
      const temp = document.createElement("div");
      temp.textContent = "aasdfas<>asdfad<>";
      this.pandogsogeon = temp.textContent;
      console.log('pando', this.pandogsogeon)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{ pandogsogeon }}
</div>
```